# matlab: change axes from px to um

Tags: matlab, scale, axis, rescale

simple question...

I have a matrix, lets `say A = magic(512)`. I display it as `imagesc(A)`. Now, I know, that 1px is equal to lets say x=15 [um]. How to display axis values in um instead of px? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is change the `XTickLabel` and `YTickLabel`. This should do the trick:

```
A = magic(512);
imagesc(A)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',15*get(gca,'XTick'));
set(gca,'YTickLabel',15*get(gca,'YTick'));
```

You use the fact that `XTick` and `XTickLabel` are usually the same and this way you avoid having to convert the chars from `XTickLabel` to numbers first. (Same goes for Y of course).

Answer (score 2):

Often I like to see two scales. I do it by overlaying a second axes.

Snippet:

```
A = magic(512);
clf
imagesc(A)
a1 = gca;
xlabel('px');ylabel('px');
set(a1,'Box','off');
a2 = axes('Color','none','XLim',get(a1,'XLim')/15,'YLim',get(a1,'YLim')/15,...
    'XAxisLocation','top','YAxisLocation','right',...
    'Position',get(a1,'Position'),'YDir','reverse',...
    'XColor','r','YColor','r');
xlabel('um');ylabel('um');
```

Has the advantage in `a2` you can draw using the x and y coordinates in the unit `[um]`.